# Hibernate and SQL join types

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple JPA entity (hibernate implementation) with an eagerly fetched relationship:

**User.java:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @OneToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_STATUS_ID", nullable = false)  
    private UserStatus userStatus;
```

**UserStatus:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_STATUS")
public class UserStatus {

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
```

and the query that is being generated to lookup the entity looks something like this:

```
...from user left outer join user_status on...
```

My question is: why is Hibernate performing this outer join and not an inner join (since I've told it that it's not nullable or optional).  Is there any way to force an inner-join?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the mapping of UserStatus ?

Comment: I've updated the question with the userStatus mapping.  There is nothing in there but for a couple of Strings, no object references.

Comment: Sorry, the hibernate version and the code of the query fetching data might also be of interest. Are you sure that it is hibernate that generated your sql ? Hibernate sql looks more like : ... from USER this_ inner join USER_STATUS userstatus1_ on this_.USER_STATUS_ID=userstatus1_.ID ... For me the userStatus was fetched  eagerly by default (as for any *ToOne mapping), and with an inner join.

Comment: If UserStatus is not nullable in User then in your database you must have that "not null" constraint in place and every entry in the USER table will have a non-null value in the USER_STATUS_ID column. In that case then it does not really matter what kind of join is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am right, Hibernate always use left outer join and you cant force hibernate to do a inner join. When you retrieve parent entity, its not mandatory that all parent entities to have child. So if inner join is used you may end up without results.